# Validate FileField django as a valid pdf

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to django and I hope you can  guide me with this, I have a model definition like this:

```
class Documents(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    path = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

But I need to validate it as a valid PDF file, could you guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should validate file upon upload. Here's a simple solution using custom model field: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2206/

So your code would be:

```
...
path = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
    upload_to='documents/',
    content_types = ['application/pdf'])
....
```

It's a good start even if you want to create more complex validation, since this one uses only  file extension checking, I guess.